# How do I take a list of urls that are stored in a csv file and import them to python to scrape and export back to csv with newly gathered data

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and BeautifulSoup and I am trying to use it to scrape multiple urls at the same time using a loop. The loop will consist of locating the banner slide on the home page of each website and get the len of how many banners that website has and place them into an excel file next to the corresponding url. I have a list of urls saved in a csv file and basically what I want to do is take each of those urls and run the loop, pulling the number of banners, and put that number next to the url into a separate column in excel.

This is the code I have so far and all it does for me is write the urls back into a csv file and gives me the number of banners for only the last url.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

with open("urls.csv", "r") as f:
csv_raw_cont=f.read()

split_csv=csv_raw_cont.split('\n')

split_csv.remove('')

separator=';'

filename = "DDC_number_of_banners.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "url, Number_of_Banners\n"

f.write(headers)

for each in split_csv:
    url_row_index=0
    url = each.split(separator)[url_row_index]
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup= BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    banner_info = soup.findAll('div',{'class':['slide', 'slide has-link', 
'html-slide slide has-link']})

    Number_of_banners = len(banner_info)

f.write(csv_raw_cont + "," + str(Number_of_banners) + "," + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: You're writing to the file outside of for loop.

Comment: Is the indentation broken?

Comment: Thanks! @JustinasMarozas, I changed that and part of the code. However, now when I open the new csv file it writes all of the urls multiple times and the number of banners are in random cells in the second column. I need help with having the loop write the list of urls once and the number of banners in the next column to the corresponding url.

Comment: @Becojo I'm not exactly sure, that is how the code was when I copied it into the question box.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a small sample of URLs as seen in `urls.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of Python's CSV library would make this a bit simpler:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import csv

with open("urls.csv", "r") as f_urls, open("DDC_number_of_banners.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['url', 'Number_of_banners'])

    for url in f_urls:
        url = url.strip()
        html = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        banner_info = soup.findAll('div',{'class':['slide', 'slide has-link', 'html-slide slide has-link']})
        csv_output.writerow([url, len(banner_info)])
```

---

To include information such as each banner's `data-label`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import csv

with open("urls.csv", "r") as f_urls, open("DDC_number_of_banners.csv", "w", newline="") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['url', 'Number_of_banners', 'data_labels'])

    for url in f_urls:
        url = url.strip()
        html = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
        banner_info = soup.findAll('div',{'class':['slide', 'slide has-link', 'html-slide slide has-link']})
        data_labels = [banner.get('data-label') for banner in banner_info]
        csv_output.writerow([url, len(banner_info)] + data_labels)
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, with the code you provided, it gives me a TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' for csv_output.writerow(['url', 'Number_of_banners']).

Comment: That means you are using Python 3.x. I have updated it to work in Python 3.x

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Will do!
One more thing, say I want to retrieve more information from those said banners, such as the data-label or data-link, could I add that to the code above?
 For example:
    first_banner_title = banner_info[0].attrs['data-label']
    first_banner_link = banner_info[0].attrs['data-link']

Comment: Here are a couple example websites: http://www.rickcaseacura.com
http://www.goodsonacura.com
http://www.edvoylesacura.com/

Comment: It can easily be added, but it is up to you how to format it. I have shown how to add `data-label` for each banner as a new column entry.